# Access Query Export to Excel with formatting

Tags: ms-access

My invoice number (Auto number) formatted like “Binu/21-22/”0000. While running the query, invoice number is showing  “Binu/21-22/0001” which exactly I want When I am exporting it to excel with following VBA code -DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "Qry_Test", acFormatXLSX, sFileName, True- that  time also excel file is showing the format  “Binu/21-22/0001” but when I am clicking on the invoice number on excel file cell then its showing only “1”. I want excel file also with the correct format “Binu/21-22/0001” instead of “1”. Anyone can help me how to resolve this”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using format option to display invoice number as `"Binu/21-22/"0000`. So when it is exporting to excel then it is exporting with format not as value. So, you can write you query with `FORMAT()` function which will display as your desired format and export to excel will export as value. Try-

```
SELECT "Binu/21-22/" & FORMAT(MyTable.[InvoiceNo],0000) as [InvoiceNo] FROM MyTable
```

Save this query and then export to excel. Add your other fields in the query. as required.

Comment: Its works perfectly. Than you So Much for your Help